# Сделать автоматический скрипт смены месяцев

Tags: javascript, php, java

Всем привет! 
Нужно сделать автоматизации, чтобы скидки менялись сами.
например, если сейчас апрель то скидка на май будет 5000 руб, а на июнь 10000 руб.
Или если уже май, то июнь 5000 руб., а на июль 10000 руб. и т. д. 
Дали задачи не могу понять, искал везде. Прошу пожалуйста показать как это можно реализовать и по возможности объяснить. Заранее благодарю!

```
                        <tr>
                        <td>
                            <b>- 5&nbsp;000&nbsp;₽</b><br>На Май 2022 
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <b>- 10&nbsp;000&nbsp;₽</b><br>На Июнь 2022
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <br><span style="font-size:120%">+ рассрочка (без&nbsp;банков и&nbsp;процентов за&nbsp;5&nbsp;минут в&nbsp;офисе)</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

Comment: Я правильно предположил, что скидка в 10000 руб. мне не светит никогда?

Comment: @LaukhinAndrey Скорее всего имеется ввиду бронь на будущие даты, тип заказываешь заранее - скидка больше

Comment: @Ceri Ясно, спасибо, а то автору было лень уточнить

Comment: @LaukhinAndrey Я прошу прощения, я тут первый раз. Извиняюсь, что не уточнил. Нет это просто привлечение клиента, не бронь ничего. А просто когда заходишь на сайт в апреле то должен стоять май и июнь, скидки не нужно трогать, тут важна сама дата. Это смена месяца по текущей дате.

Comment: @nik1224 Вы все же уточните, мне не понятно, что такое "смена месяца" на сайте. Как понимать, что на сайте должен стоять май и июнь? Просто написано где-то на странице?

Comment: @LaukhinAndrey ну да должна на сайте есть блок "Акции" в блоке два месяца и под каждым месяцем размер скидки. Нужно, чтобы была автоматическая смены месяцев. Например Апрель на сайте мая и июнь, Если май на сайте июнь и июль, Если июнь на сайте июль и август.

Comment: js, java, php... осталось добавить микрокаклькулятор мк-85, счеты. вам какое решение надо?

Answer (score 0):

Можете попробовать через массив

```js
const d = new Date();

// Ключ это месяц (0 - Январь, 1 - Февраль ... 11 - Декабрь)
// Значение это цена

const skidki = {
  0: '200',
  1: '300',
  2: '200',
  3: '500',
  4: '200',
  5: '200',
  6: '200',
  7: '200',
  8: '200',
  9: '200',
  10: '200',
  11: '200'
};

let month = d.getMonth();

console.log(skidki[month]);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Это смена двух месяцев? Мне нужно получается смену двух месяцев на сайте.

Answer (score 0):

Можете попробовать так:

```js
const months = ['Январь', 'Февраль', 'Март', 'Апрель', 'Май', 'Июнь', 'Июль', 'Август', 'Сентябрь', 'Октябрь', 'Ноябрь', 'Декабрь'];



const currentMonthNumber = new Date().getMonth(); //Можете заменить нужным числом, если не нужен текущий

const monthsNumbers = [
  currentMonthNumber,
  currentMonthNumber + 1,
  currentMonthNumber + 2
].map(x => (x + months.length) % months.length);

const currentMonthSpan = document.querySelector('#currentMonth');
const nextMonthSpan = document.querySelector('#nextMonth');
const nextNextMonthSpan = document.querySelector('#nextNextMonth');

[currentMonthSpan, nextMonthSpan, nextNextMonthSpan].forEach((monthSpan, index) => {
  monthSpan.textContent = months[monthsNumbers[index]];
})
```

```html
<div>
  К сожалению в этом меясце (<span id="currentMonth"></span>) нет скидок
</div>

<div>
  Но в следующем месяце (<span id="nextMonth"></span>) будет скидка в 5000 рублей
</div>

<div>
  А в последущем месяце (<span id="nextNextMonth"></span>) будет безумная скидка в 10000 рублей
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо большое!

Comment: А чтобы он не выводил текущую дату и фразу, нужно просто убрать const currentMonthSpan = document.querySelector('#currentMonth');

Comment: В общем у меня сейчас на сайте так:
      <tr>
       <td>
        <b>- 5&nbsp;000&nbsp;₽</b><br>На Май 2022 
       </td>
       <td>
        <b>- 10&nbsp;000&nbsp;₽</b><br>На Июнь 2022
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td colspan="2">
        <br><span style="font-size:120%">+ рассрочка (без&nbsp;банков и&nbsp;процентов за&nbsp;5&nbsp;минут в&nbsp;офисе)</span>
       </td>
      </tr>

Comment: @nik1224 Во первых это, потом убрать `currentMonthNumber` из массива `monthsNumbers` и первый `div` надо будет убрать из вёрстки

Comment: @nik1224 Пожалуйста на вставляйте в комментарии такие куски кода, их невозможно читать. Лучше вставьте ваш код как дополнение к вашему вопросу, чтобы все могли увидеть это

Comment: понял я извиняюсь,  исправлю.

Comment: Добавил))))))))))

Comment: А я как понял обязательно должен быть span?

Comment: @nik1224 Ну насколько я вижу по вашей вёрстке, вам просто надо вместо конкретных названий месяцев написать `span`  элементы как у меня с `id` и всё будет работать)

Comment: @nik1224 Ну не обязательно `span` просто это строчный элемент, который не ломает вёрстку, потому его использовал, а так можете использовать что-то другое по желанию

Answer (score 0):

```js
const discounts = [5000, 10000];
const months = [
  'январе', 'феврале', 'марте',
  'апреле', 'мае', 'июне',
  'июле', 'августе', 'сентябре',
  'октябре', 'ноябре', 'декабре'
];

const date = new Date();
let month = date.getMonth();

document.body.innerText =
  'В '   + months[++month % 12] + ' Вас ждет скидка ' + discounts[0] + ' руб., ' +
  'а в ' + months[++month % 12] + ' Вас ждет скидка ' + discounts[1] +
  ' руб. Но это не точно.';
```

Comment: спасибо огромное!